# style.visibility='hidden' in JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a Javascript code that handles onchange and onfocus event on my combo box. So that it shows only the one that is being selected by the user on the combo box.

I have this Javascript code:

```
var prev = "";

function pagechange(topage) {
frompage = prev;
  var page=document.getElementById('formpage_'+frompage);
  if (!page) return false;
  page.style.display='none';
  page.style.visibility='hidden';

  page=document.getElementById('formpage_'+topage);
  if (!page) return false;
  page.style.display='block';
  page.style.visibility='visible';

  return true;
}


function set(){
var e = document.getElementById("usertype");
var selection = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
pagechange(selection);
}


function getPrevious(){
var e = document.getElementById("usertype");
var selection = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;    
prev = selection;

}
```

And this one is for my combo box:

```
      <select id="usertype" name="usertype" class="dropdown-select" autofocus="autofocus" onchange="set()" onfocus="getPrevious()" >
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Chairperson</option>
        <option value="2">Dean</option>
        <option value="3">Faculty</option>
        <option value="4">Staff</option>
        <option value="5">Student</option>
        <option value="6">Admin</option>
      </select>
```

I've tried it. Yes, it shows what the user has selected but it does not hide the previous one.

What do you think is wrong in my code? or what must be modified?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but there's no need to change the `visibility` at all if you're setting `display:none`.

Comment: Well the first time that "pagechange()" runs, won't "prev" be empty? Won't that make the function exit immediately?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes but it will eat some space in the page because it's not hidden.

Comment: @Harvey yes, but my point is that "prev" will *never* be set, right? ... oh wait - I see. Well I think Shadow Wizard has got you covered.

Comment: @Pointy I don't think so because I have my onfocus event so that 'prev' will be set. I don't know that's what I think.

Comment: @Harvey no, onfocus was not triggered. you can use console.log to verify this using your old code.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hmm.. I see, okay I understand now. But where can I find console.log? Sorry I'm newbie in Javascript.

Comment: @Harvey it's there, just use it e.g. `console.log("hello there")` then open the browser JavaScript console. Even IE supports this, since IE9 or IE10. I would have suggested using `alert()` to debug, but in the specific case of `focus()` it's a sure recipe to endless loop.

Comment: _"Yes but it will eat some space in the page because it's not hidden."_ - No it won't. `display:none` hides the element without reserving the space in the layout (i.e., other elements will move up to fill the gap). `visibility:hidden` hides the element keeping the space in the layout (i.e., other elements will _not_ move up to fill the gap). So there's no reason to use both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too much faith in the `onfocus` event. Unlike what you expect, it's not always triggered before new selection is made. For example (at least in Chrome) if you just click the arrow and change selection, it won't be triggered. Hence, you don't have the previous selection to hide.

Just get rid of the `getPrevious()` method and instead store the previous after showing selected:

```
function pagechange(topage) {
    var page;
    if (prev.length > 0) {
        page = document.getElementById('formpage_' + prev);
        if (page)
            page.style.display = 'none';
    }

    page = document.getElementById('formpage_' + topage);
    if (!page)
        return false;

    page.style.display = 'block';
    prev = topage;
    return true;
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/TK3xa/1/).

If you insist on changing visibility as well be my guest, but it won't make any difference thus removed in my example. (if you can prove otherwise I'll be glad to stand corrected)